# What is the type of a setInterval function if i want to store it in local state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to store my setInterval in local state , but I have a problem with how to describe the state I mean what kind of type is the set interval I tried to use ()=> void but no luck with it ?

```js
 const [counter, setCounter] = useState<() => void>();


const setTime = () => {
    setCounter(
      setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((prevState) => ({ minutes: prevState.minutes, seconds: prevState.seconds - 1 }));
      }, 1000)
    );
  };
```

Comment: You mean its return type? Then it is `number` (timer ID)

Comment: well I want to describe the use State

Comment: From your code - you're passing `number` to `setCounter` hence it will be `useState<number>();` ** This is without understanding the logic behind 

Comment: @AlekseyL. Argument of type 'Timer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number | undefined>'.
  Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type '(prevState: number | undefined) => number | undefined'.

Comment: Try calling `window.setInterval` otherwise typescript picks NodeJs typings for `setInterval`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let i: NodeJS.Timer = setInterval(() => {},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[declare function setInterval(handler: TimerHandler, timeout?: number, ...arguments: any[]): number;](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3ef3cdddb338b8f0e6a2c5971d255390b68654ac/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18666)

This can also be viewed by doing a `Go To Definition` if your editor supports that. It's a native function, so it's type comes pre-packaged with typescript distribution, and is available within `lib.dom.d.ts`.

Comment: `It's a native function, so it's type comes pre-packaged with typescript distribution` this is not really true, `setTimeout` is not part of TypeScript or JavaScript language specification, it is part of the API provided by the browser or nodejs (which is also indicated by the fact that it is described in `lib.dom.d.ts`)

Comment: @t.niese `lib.dom.d.ts` is a file within the distribution of typescript, I think the way it is phrased is valid.